# RubyMine and PhpStorm "Complete Installation" blank window in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.10, phpstorm, rubymine

I attempted to install RubyMine and PhpStorm according to their instructions, but both simply pop up a blank dialog box that says "Complete Installation" at the top.  I can't close the windows or otherwise kill the process (that I can tell).

I installed them in the /opt/ directory at the recommendation of several online resources.  I have also double checked that I have Java installed (v1.7.0_17-b02(, which is required by both.

```
  1. Unpack the RubyMine distribution archive that you downloaded to
     where you wish to install the program. We will refer to this destination
     location as your {installation home} below.

  2. Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type:

       ./rubymine.sh

     to start the application.
```

Comment: Please check if [this helps](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java).

Comment: Wow, thank you, that was it!  I would have been looking around for that for quite a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per CrazyCoder's link, I opened the terminal and ran

```
_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

And then everything worked like a charm.